# A question about a family of nilpotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras

Consider a family of $n\times n$ matrices $\left\{A_{i}\right\}$, where $A_i$ are all nilpotents and pair-wise commutative.

First question:If there exists some positive $N$ s.t. $A_{j_1}A_{j_2}\cdots A_{j_N}=0$ for all $A_{j_1},A_{j_2},\cdots, A_{j_n}\in \left\{A_{i}\right\}$.

Second question:If we consider the algebra $A$ generated by $\left\{A_{i}\right\}$, we can ask a stronger question:Is $A$ a nilpotent algebra?

If the $\left\{A_{i}\right\}$ is finite with $m$ elements, the question is trivial, we can take $N=mn$, but I don't know the answer if $\left\{A_{i}\right\}$ is infinite.

I think these two questions are related to the theory of Lie algebra .

Comment: If you are considering matrices over $\mathbb{C}$, then commuting matrices are simultaneously triangonalizable, so the answer to your first question is yes, with $N = n$. Actually that works for all fields

Comment: @Jan, Thanks for your comment , but could you be more specific?

Comment: @Jan I got it. Indeed, every product of n strictly triangular matrix is always zero.

Comment: Take a basis for the vector space spanned by the $A_i$. This will be finite, and now your bound works.